# DecodeError: Wrong wire type in tag. | import tensorflow in Atom+Hydrogen

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, hydrogen

I am attempting to import tensorflow - my kernel is an anaconda environment. When I run "import tensorflow" using the Anaconda terminal it works perfectly but once I try the same in Atom it throws the following Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DecodeError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d6579f534729> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=g-bad-import-order
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
     25 
     26 from tensorflow._api.v1 import app

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     50 
     51 # Protocol buffers
---> 52 from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
     53 from tensorflow.core.framework.node_def_pb2 import *
     54 from tensorflow.core.framework.summary_pb2 import *

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py in <module>
     13 
     14 
---> 15 from tensorflow.core.framework import node_def_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_node__def__pb2
     16 from tensorflow.core.framework import function_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_function__pb2
     17 from tensorflow.core.framework import versions_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_versions__pb2

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\node_def_pb2.py in <module>
     13 
     14 
---> 15 from tensorflow.core.framework import attr_value_pb2 as tensorflow_dot_core_dot_framework_dot_attr__value__pb2
     16 
     17 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\attr_value_pb2.py in <module>
    346   AttrEntry = _reflection.GeneratedProtocolMessageType('AttrEntry', (_message.Message,), dict(
    347     DESCRIPTOR = _NAMEATTRLIST_ATTRENTRY,
--> 348     __module__ = 'tensorflow.core.framework.attr_value_pb2'
    349     # @@protoc_insertion_point(class_scope:tensorflow.NameAttrList.AttrEntry)
    350     ))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.py in __init__(cls, name, bases, dictionary)
    181     cls._decoders_by_tag = {}
    182     if (descriptor.has_options and
--> 183         descriptor.GetOptions().message_set_wire_format):
    184       cls._decoders_by_tag[decoder.MESSAGE_SET_ITEM_TAG] = (
    185           decoder.MessageSetItemDecoder(descriptor), None)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py in GetOptions(self)
    158       else:
    159         self._options = _ParseOptions(options_class(),
--> 160                                       self._serialized_options)
    161 
    162       return self._options

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py in _ParseOptions(message, string)
    924   proto2 files. It must not be used outside proto2.
    925   """
--> 926   message.ParseFromString(string)
    927   return message
    928 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\message.py in ParseFromString(self, serialized)
    185     """
    186     self.Clear()
--> 187     return self.MergeFromString(serialized)
    188 
    189   def SerializeToString(self, **kwargs):

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.py in MergeFromString(self, serialized)
   1123     length = len(serialized)
   1124     try:
-> 1125       if self._InternalParse(serialized, 0, length) != length:
   1126         # The only reason _InternalParse would return early is if it
   1127         # encountered an end-group tag.

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\python_message.py in InternalParse(self, buffer, pos, end)
   1175         old_pos = new_pos
   1176         (data, new_pos) = decoder._DecodeUnknownField(
-> 1177             buffer, new_pos, wire_type)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1178         if new_pos == -1:
   1179           return pos

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\internal\decoder.py in _DecodeUnknownField(buffer, pos, wire_type)
    950     return (0, -1)
    951   else:
--> 952     raise _DecodeError('Wrong wire type in tag.')
    953 
    954   return (data, pos)

DecodeError: Wrong wire type in tag.
```

Let me know if you have any idea how to fix that!

Using windows 10, python 3.7, anaconda and hydrogen. Computer restart and tensorflow/protobuf reinstall haven't helped.

Thanks!

Comment: The error can be caused by the incompatible protobuf library. What is the version of your protobuf? You may try looking for a protocol buffer package that supports atom.

Comment: Running protoc --version in Atom returns "libprotoc 3.8.0", in Anaconda it is "libprotoc 3.11.4"

If I run !pip install protobuf>3.11.0 in Atom though it still returns the the same "libprotoc 3.8.0" afterwards